# Firebase won't save keys with null values

Tags: javascript, object, firebase

I have an object like:

```
var _json = { "objects":[{
    "type":"path", "originX":"center", "originY":"center", "left":48.59, 
    "top":132.5, "width":64.5,"height":173, "fill":null,"stroke":"#3f7cc4", 
    "strokeWidth":12,"strokeDashArray":null
}]}
```

I save this object using Firebase as:

```
var myDataRef = new Firebase(<...>);
myDataRef.child("saved_projects").child(authData.uid).update({'P3': _json});
```

But, when I retrieve the same using Firebase `on` method and get the value as:

```
snapshot.val()
```

I get the object but keys with `null` values got removed i.e. I only got:

```
{"objects":[ {"type":"path", "originX":"center", 
 "originY":"center","left":48.59, "top":132.5,"width":64.5, 
 "height":173, "stroke":"#3f7cc4","strokeWidth":12
}]}
```

This is causing me some weird issues since I'm using `Fabric.js` and it needs these values.
Please help!

**EDIT / UPDATE(Hack)**

For the time being, I'm using a weird HACK, before storing the object to Firebase I'm converting all the `null` values to `0`. But I want to know a nicer way to do.

```
function recursivelyReplaceNullToZero(j) {
    for (var i in j){
        if (typeof j[i] === "object") {
            recursivelyReplaceNullToZero(j[i]);
        }
        if (j[i] === null) {
            j[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
recursivelyReplaceNullToZero(_json);
```

Comment: Firebase removes nodes that have null values, there is not much we can help you with there. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html "Passing null for the new value is equivalent to calling remove(); all data at this location or any child location will be deleted."

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) and you should probably start with the (flawed?) use case you are trying to resolve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the time being I'm using a weird HACK, before storing the object to Firebase I'm converting all the null values to 0. But I want to know much nicer way, please!

```
function recursivelyReplaceNullToZero(j) {
    for (var i in j){
        if (typeof j[i] === "object") {
            recursivelyReplaceNullToZero(j[i]);
        }
        if (j[i] === null) {
            j[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
recursivelyReplaceNullToZero(_json);
```

Comment: I think that `0` is a common value , it may conflict `null` with real integer `0`. So, I suggest to recursive convert `null`  to `Null` (string type) , & reverse this conversion on `getter` function.

Comment: Yes, It will work, but you ensure that there is no conflict; i.e:. No variable in your application may equal to `String(Null)`. If any; You should design escape mechanism.

Comment: Other official way is to let firebase to delete the key if its value equal to `null`. then , In your `getter` you could discover it. `if (!db.ref().child(path).value){ //do something}` ; the second scenario if you get the parent ref, You should recursively iterate over keys by methods like `if (!value.hasOwnProperty(NullableKey)){//the key equal to null or not defined at all// doSomething}`

Answer (score 0):

`fill` would be a type `string` and those can be empty in Firestore.
`strokeDashArray` would be a type `array` and those can contain empty `string`s as well (among other data types). See image below which is a screenshot of Firestore.  You are correct about `null` though, it won't store properties with value `null`.

Remember though that Firestore is a document database, and is schema-less - meaning that not every document is required to have all fields (semi-structured).

So, instead of storing value-less properties, simply handle the possibility that the property may not be there in your code, e.g.,

```
if(doc.exists){
  if(doc.data().fill){
    // now you do what you want with the fill property
  } else {
    // there is no fill data
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

This is expected behavior. AFAIK `json` systems work like this.

You should instead in your code set nulls for the keys that are not present in the database.
As an analogy: think of the leading zeroes - you **DON'T** write in front of a number.

Comment: json *can* have null : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp

Comment: @anshsachdeva I never said that json cannot have nulls. My indication was towards not *requiring* to have obvious nulls in datastores..