# Firebase Realtime Database Skipping some fields from JSON

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am saving the following JSON in Firebase Realtime Database! Interestingly when I import the Fixtures JSON or write it from Firebase Cloud Functions on Realtime Database it excludes the `result` and `obj`.

Original JSON:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/fixtures/165069"
    },
    "competition": {
      "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/467"
    },
    "homeTeam": {
      "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/808"
    },
    "awayTeam": {
      "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/801"
    }
  },
  "date": "2018-06-14T15:00:00Z",
  "status": "TIMED",
  "matchday": 1,
  "homeTeamName": "Russia",
  "awayTeamName": "Saudi Arabia",
  "result": {
    "goalsHomeTeam": null,
    "goalsAwayTeam": null
  },
  "odds": null
}
```

The result and odds key/value pairs disappear when I copy/past the JSON. Following Picture shows it from the Firebase Realtime Database. 
[image]

What might be wrong? And how to correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the values of `result` and `odd` are "null". Firebase does not support Null values. Checkout out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580844/firebase-wont-save-keys-with-null-values). That question references the documentation for Firebase, which includes this line:

*Passing null for the new value is equivalent to calling remove(); all data at this location or any child location will be deleted.*

Answer (score 1):

I seems like Firebase Realtime Database does not like null values! So I have to set `odds` and all values of `result` to something to have this fixed! The working JSON is:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/fixtures/165069"
    },
    "competition": {
      "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/467"
    },
    "homeTeam": {
      "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/808"
    },
    "awayTeam": {
      "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/801"
    }
  },
  "date": "2018-06-14T15:00:00Z",
  "status": "TIMED",
  "matchday": 1,
  "homeTeamName": "Russia",
  "awayTeamName": "Saudi Arabia",
  "result": {
    "goalsHomeTeam": "null",
    "goalsAwayTeam": "null"
  },
  "odds": "null"
}
```