# How to set undefined or null to value in firebase object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to set null or undefined to value in Fireabase object like below:

```
const updateObject: Partial<SomeObject> = {
    name: "new name",
    age: undefined
}

userPlanReference.update(updateObject);
```

and when I run this code above and look at the object in firebase app, i see that my `name` is updated but `age` is not undefined, so, he was not updated and value is still like before update, can someone tell me how to set null or undefined into firebase object?, i need to hide this `age` value in the object, but it not work with set undefined, thanks for any help

Comment: You can undefine a prop with `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()`.  A literal `null` should work for a null value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase won't save keys with null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580844/firebase-wont-save-keys-with-null-values)

Comment: @danh I can't cause my FieldValue is not assignable to type number :/

Comment: Please show the interface for your custom object, SomeObject

Comment: @Hydra `age?: number`

Comment: @methodinvocation are you trying to remove the field or set it's value to undefined? You won't be able to set it to undefined, but you can set it to null if that's what you would like to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Undefined is not a valid type for Firestore fields, but null is. In order to change `age` to null without removing it from your document, you'll have to update your SomeObject to accept a number or null. Since you did not specify a language, I've written it in Typescript.

```ts
export interface SomeObject {
  name: string;
  age?: number | null; // accept null values
}
```

Then, update the code you have to set age to null

```ts
const updateObject: Partial<SomeObject> = {
    name: "new name",
    age: null
}

userPlanReference.update(updateObject);
```